# When using Okta as an IdP with SP initiated workflow, login never leaves Okta portal

Tags: saml-2.0

So I am trying to setup Okta as an identity provider, and I want to login to an application using the Service Provider initiated workflow. I've setup the template SAML 2.0 application in Okta and setup the entry point and SAML certificate on the Service provider. The Service Provider initiates the workflow just fine, a popup opens with the Okta login dialogue. But once the login is complete I am taken into the Okta portal with a list of my apps. What should be happening is a re-direct back to the Service Provider so that it can use the userID to login the user there.

I followed the instruction here for setting up the IdP https://support.okta.com/entries/23364161-Configuring-Okta-Template-SAML-2-0-application

Here is what my config in Okta looks like

```
Application Label: App Name
Force Authentication: no
Name ID format: EmailAddress
Recipient: https://serviceprovider.com/_saml/validate/okta/
Audience Restriction: https://serviceprovider.com/
authnContextClassRef: Password Protected Transport
Destination: https://serviceprovider.com/_saml/validate/okta/
Response: signed
Assertion: signed
Request: uncompressed
Default Relay State: Leave blank since we are only doing SP initiated workflow
Post Back URL: https://serviceprovider.com/_saml/validate/okta/
Attribute Statements: none
Group Name: leave blank
Group filter: leave blank
```

I don't see any errors in the Okta portal or in the Okta administration panel, so I can't figure out why it is not completing the workflow and re-directing back to the SP.
Is there a place in Okta to see any errors that might be getting thrown by the process?

Anyone know what might be up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back. In my case, the "Rquest" was set to "compressed". changing it to "uncompressed" solved the issue. But in your case I see it is already "uncompressed"...

However, try to contact OKTA's support - they can help you out.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I had the opposite problem, I needed to set mine to "compressed" rather than "uncompressed"

Comment: Had the same problem here and setting it to compressed fixed it for me. Thanks to everyone who contributed in this thead.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is different depending on the type of SAML HTTP BINDING used for the SAML Authentication Request.

For HTTP Redirect Bindings you need to set the Okta Request to "compressed".

For HTTP POST Bindings you need to set the Okta Request to "uncompressed".